# Printing from Android app to an Local ethernet connected printer ( Not over Internet)

Tags: android, printing, android-print-framework

I am new to Android printing framework. My requirement is to print document from my app to printer which is connected to Local ethernet ( Not over internet ). is it possible in Android printing framework. How my app and printer will communicate?? Please Help

Comment: Talk to the printer manufacturer.

Comment: @CommonsWare. Can you please elaborate please. How my app and printer will communicate?? Since printer is connected to local ethernet ?

Comment: "Can you please elaborate please" -- your printer is a piece of equipment. It was manufactured by some company. Only that company can tell you if they offer Android printing support for your particular scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using the PrintHelper available in the V4 Support Library.

```
private void doPhotoPrint() {
    PrintHelper photoPrinter = new PrintHelper(getActivity());
    photoPrinter.setScaleMode(PrintHelper.SCALE_MODE_FIT);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.droids);
    photoPrinter.printBitmap("droids.jpg - test print", bitmap);
}
```

For more information, follow this link:

https://developer.android.com/training/printing/photos.html

Comment: How my app and printer will communicate?? Since printer is connected to local ethernet

Comment: PrintHelper will open a dialog which will allow you to select a printer.  There should be a list of printers that are available on your Local Area Network.  If you have a printer connected to your WiFi, you should see it available.  Once selected and Print  button on dialog pressed, your document will be sent to the printer over WiFi.

Comment: My printers are not connected to wifi, they are connected with LAN

Comment: As long as your phone is connected to the same LAN, it's not an issue.  I would assume that your phone connects to the LAN via WiFi.  The printer can be wired into the LAN, as long as it is on the same LAN that the phone is on.